# Integrating PayPal-iOS-SDK pod with RubyMotion

Tags: ios, paypal, rubymotion

I'm integrating PayPal-iOS-SDK pod with RubyMotion but the app crashes when running this line of code:

```
subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPriceForItems(items)
```

I'm trying to port this Objective-C code to RubyMotion

```
    PayPalItem *item1 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Blue Jeans"

                                  withQuantity:2

                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"34.89"]

                                  withCurrency:@"USD"

                                       withSku:@"Hip-00010"];

  PayPalItem *item2 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Red Jeans"

                                  withQuantity:1

                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"0.00"]

                                  withCurrency:@"USD"

                                       withSku:@"Hip-00020"];

  PayPalItem *item3 = [PayPalItem itemWithName:@"Black Jeans"

                                  withQuantity:1

                                     withPrice:[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"29.99"]

                                  withCurrency:@"USD"

                                       withSku:@"Hip-00030"];

  NSArray *items = @[item1, item2, item3];

  NSDecimalNumber *subtotal = [PayPalItem totalPriceForItems:items];
```

This is my RubyMotion code:

```
item1 = PayPalItem.itemWithName('Blue Jeans',
                   withQuantity: 2,
                   withPrice: NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('34.89'),
                   withCurrency: 'USD',
                   withSku: 'Hip-00010')

item2 = PayPalItem.itemWithName('Red Jeans',
                   withQuantity: 1,
                   withPrice: NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('0.00'),
                   withCurrency: 'USD',
                   withSku: 'Hip-00020')

item3 = PayPalItem.itemWithName('Black Jeans',
                   withQuantity: 1,
                   withPrice: NSDecimalNumber.decimalNumberWithString('29.99'),
                   withCurrency: 'USD',
                   withSku: 'Hip-00030')

items = [item1, item2, item3]

subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPriceForItems(items)
```

But the app crashes when it gets to this line:

```
subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPriceForItems(items)
```

This is the error that I get:

2014-05-08 19:26:56.492 B4TS[8230:70b] -[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcae0550
2014-05-08 19:26:57.808 B4TS[8230:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xcae0550'

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: What is the totalPriceForItems method doing can you post it? The error suggests your sending that method something it doesn't expect.

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: I noticed that in the Objective-C code you are working with pointers and you are giving a pointer array. In the ruby code you are giving the objects themselves (which should but doesn't necessarily translate to pointers, i'm new to iOS)... Did you try using the MotionRuby pointer system instead (like in the error references coding)?